# jQuery onblur is not displaying a value after you click out from a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason, i can not figure out why i can not get the onblur property to work. What I would like to have happen is if someone clicks into a text box and does not type anything, I would like for that to display TBD, but if they do enter in a value, to display that value. I have an input mask active as well.I cannot seem to figure this out, and I am not sure why. I feel like I am missing something very small that it is just going over my head. Here is the code that I have for my script.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $.mask.definitions['~'] = '[+-]';
    $('.run').mask('99:99');
    $('.run').val('TBD');
    $('.penalty').mask('99:99');
    $('.penalty').val('TBD');
    $('.com').val('TBD');

})

var defaultValues = {
    'dfb_run': "TBD"
};

$('input').live('blur', function() {
    var x = $(this);
    var run = x.attr('id');

    if (x.val().match(/^[\s\.]*$/)) {

        if (run == 'dfb_run') {
            x.unmask();
        }
        x.val(defaultValues[dfb_run]);
    }
});
```

Here is what i have in the body

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td> Site:
          <input type = "text" value = "DFB" readonly = "true" size = "4"> </td>
      <td> Run Time:
          <input type = "text" size = "5" id = "dfb_run" class = "run" name = "dfb_run" value = "TBD"> </td>
      <td> Penalty:
          <input type = "text" class = "penalty" size = "5" id = "dfb_pen" name = "dfb_pen"> </td>
      <td> Completed Time:
          <input type = "text" readonly = "true" size = "5" id = "dfb_com" name = "dfb_com" class = "com"> </td>
      <td>
          <input type = "button" value = "calculate" onclick = dfbcalc() id = "dfbcalcu">
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I used this jsfiddle as a reference because it has the same affect that I am looking for. http://jsfiddle.net/RuFHK/16/

Answer (score 1):

In the `html` you are setting the `value` attribute for the `input tags` and `on blur` you are getting the values from `input` and checking if it is empty.

Since you have already assigned a value for the input, it will never be empty and it will not pass over this if condition

```
if (x.val().match(/^[\s\.]*$/))
```

because the input tag has a value by default.

I guess you need to replace the `value` attribute with `placeholder`, so that there is no default value for input and when the user leaves it empty it will pass through the if condition in your code.

Hope this helps.

Updated JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RuFHK/18/ with `placeholder` instead of `value` attribute.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I tried using the `placeholder` attribute and it did not do exactly what i was looking for. The part that did not work for me is if i click on a submit button, the placeholder value does not get carried over as well. What I have going on is there is a php page that gets this information. On the php page when i use placeholder attr, the box pulling in that info is left blank